# Unable to catkin_make due to missing yocs_msgs/JoystickConfig.h

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Needed to use Yujin's Velocity Smoother, but unable to catkin_make due to missing file. No one else seemed to have this issue hence I'm opening a new question. I git cloned the devel branch.

Here is the error I got:

```
/home/bla/catkin_ws/src/yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/src/joyop.cpp:15:38: fatal error: yocs_msgs/JoystickConfig.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/src/joyop.cpp.o' failed

make[2]: *** [yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/src/joyop.cpp.o] Error 1

CMakeFiles/Makefile2:25342: recipe for target 'yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/all' failed   
make[1]: *** [yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/all] Error 2
```

make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280660/unable-to-catkin_make-due-to-missing-yocs_msgs/joystickconfig.h/) by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs/blob/devel/dynamic_reconfigure/Joystick.cfg) is the file that will generate `yocs_msgs/JoystickConfig.h`. In your workspace have you cloned the [yocs_msgs](https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs) repository in addition to the [yujin_ocs](https://github.com/yujinrobot/yujin_ocs) repository?

**Update**
Based on a comment from @gvdhoorn I was able to see that the packages you want are available from the ROS apt repositories. I recommend installing the packages rather than building from source, unless there is a specific reason you need a feature from the source version that is not available in the apt version.

Running the command @gvdhoorn indicated will get you everything you need, including dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-$distro-yocs-velocity-smoother
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
@Alsing: @Thomas D is probably right: you're missing dependencies.

See #q252478 for a generic recipe for installing packages from source.

And note that the pkg has been released for both Indigo and Kinetic, so a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-$distro-yocs-velocity-smoother
```

should work.

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2018-01-24**:
@Thomas D didn't realise I needed o compile yocs_msgs seperately. Thanks for the help!

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2018-01-24**:
@gvdhoon I compiled instead :)

**Comment by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on 2019-05-06**:
Hello, I had met the similar issue, I already follow the above suggestion to :
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-yocs-velocity-smoother

The installation works fine, and the build already passed, but looks I have the link issue and compilation terminated:

/home/{usersname}/catkin_ws/src/yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/src/joyop.cpp:15:38: fatal error: yocs_msgs/JoystickConfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/src/joyop.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/src/joyop.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:8887: recipe for target 'yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failed

Anyone can help? I am newbie for the ROS actually,

**Comment by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on 2019-05-06**:
Do I need git clone the yocs_msgs and compile it? I think I already install it:

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-yocs-msgs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ros-kinetic-yocs-msgs is already the newest version (0.6.3-0xenial-20181107-005535-0800).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-06**:
@macleonsh: please post a new question. Don't post a follow-up question under the answer of an already resolved one.

If your issue is related, refer to this question in your new question.

**Comment by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on 2019-05-07**:
Thanks, I git clone https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs.git and rebuild, now issue solved. Thanks anyway!